# A way to call a method everytime a sessionscoped bean is accessed?

Tags: jsf, session-scope

I want a method to be called everytime a request to a SessionScoped bean is made.

How can I do this?

It is like @PostConstruct, but I want this method to be called, for example everytime a request to a page that is backed by this bean is accessed.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for `@ViewScoped`, not for `@SessionScoped`. I would recommend you to use JSF 2.2 and the new `@ViewScoped` annotation for CDI: http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087 (since in older questions you noted you're using CDI).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The bean should hold its properties through a session however. Like a property counter. I want to see how many times this bean has been accessed by the container through the session, either by POST or GET request.

Comment: Then you can have the data in a `@SessionScoped` bean and update it by injecting the bean in a `@RequestScoped` bean that points to this page instead.

Comment: Here's more on what @LuiggiMendoza had to say. Forget the filter, it was an inelegant solution and I'm deleting my answer. *it would be better having a `@RequestScoped` bean that will handle the access to the page, injection a `@SessionScoped` bean that handles the counter and update the counter value in the `@PostConstruct` method of the `@RequestScoped`. Still, if you want a counter for the page available for the whole site (not just the session) you should inject an `@ApplicationScoped` instead. Also, make sure that your counter variable is modified in a synchronize block.*

Comment: It is interesting @LuiggiMendoza finds time to learn stuff in between all the judging duty he has.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Luiggi get ready, I am about the ask a question. Are you ready to downvote and press the close button and talk to me about my learning difficulties? Tell me when you are ready, I don't want to miss the fun!

Comment: If you haven't searched on the subject and ask a duplucated question, then yes I will mark it as possible dup. About downvoting, it depends on community users, not just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Interceptor` on class level, more information: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/ses30cfg008.htm#BCGDHEBF

Comment: But my backing bean is a #Named and #SessionScoped bean. Can it also be a #Stateful bean? Sorry if the question is dumb, I am pretty new to Java.